# Coinspot REST API - C#

Tags: c#, json, rest, api, bitcoin

I'm trying to hit the Coinspot REST API, but I'm getting an error returned. I'm having no trouble talking to Bittrex and Independent Reserve, but Coinspot is a bit different. This is my code:

```
    protected override RESTClient RESTClient { get; } = new RESTClient(new NewtonsoftSerializationAdapter(), new Uri("https://www.coinspot.com.au/api"));

    public class postdata
    {
        public string nonce { get; set; }
    }

    public string CalculateMD5Hash(string input)
    {
        //step 1, calculate MD5 hash from input

        MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
        var inputBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
        var hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

        // step 2, convert byte array to hex string
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Private IR Call: GetAccounts
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private async Task<List<AccountHolding>> Balances()
    {

        //https://github.com/geekpete/py-coinspot-api/blob/master/coinspot/coinspot.py

        //var nonce = new Date().getTime();

        //var postdata = postdata || { };
        //postdata.nonce = nonce;

        //var stringmessage = JSON.stringify(postdata);
        //var signedMessage = new hmac("sha512", self.secret);

        //signedMessage.update(stringmessage);

        // 'sign': sign,
        //'key': self.key

        var nonce = APIHelpers.GetNonce();

        var postdata = new postdata { nonce = nonce };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postdata);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(json);

        var sign = APIHelpers.GetHMACSHAHash(ApiSecret, json, APIHelpers.HMACSHAType.NineBit);

        //Do we do this?
        //The JavaScript samples seem to hash with MD5 afterwards for double encryption?
        sign = CalculateMD5Hash(sign);

        RESTClient.Headers.Clear();
        RESTClient.Headers.Add("sign", sign);
        RESTClient.Headers.Add("key", ApiKey);

        try
        {
            var retVal = await RESTClient.PostAsync<string, postdata>(postdata, "/my/balances");

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(retVal);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

The doco is very scant! I'm stuck.
https://www.coinspot.com.au/api

I don't have the error handy right now, but it was a completely non-descript error with information about what went wrong. It was something like "invalid call". But, I know that it is accepted my posted data to some extent, because if I change the name of the property "nonce" to "noncey", I get a meaningful error back that says "no nonce".

Comment: Do you want to tell us the error?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to include it, but I'm away from my computer right now. It was very non-descript. It was something like "invalid" with no explanation whatsoever.

Comment: can confirm, error (in json) looks like 
'{
    "status": "invalid"
}'

Answer (score 2):

Did you ever manage to get this API working. CoinSpot are not very supportive of this. I can only get 3 of the coins API working which isn't much help

Comment: Nope. It looks like it half works but I was never able to connect. If you contact them and they reply to you, I'd like to hear about it. Meantime I've asked them to disable by api key and they haven't even managed that.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working recently and put together a simple SDK in .NET

https://github.com/QuintinHumphreys/CoinspotAPI

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

**tl:dr** It's undocumented but you need to use port 443, I found it by digging through their node SDK.

I was having the same issue, getting the very non-descriptive {status: invalid} response, in my case using Elixir not C#. I got it to work by peeking into their node SDK - my details worked using their SDK so I knew it had to be something I wasn't doing properly (although their documentation is pretty shocking). They use port 443 and as soon as I set that it worked.

I tried 2 things, I'm 90% sure it was the port number but half way through my getting it to work I printed the sha512 sign created by their node sdk and compared it to the one I generating using [Cryptex](https://github.com/impl/cryptex) I saw that they were generating the same sha512 signature, but my one was in capital letters while the node one was in lowercase - this may or may not end up mattering but I did use String.downcase() on mine in the end.